# SQuirrel SQL client with hibernate 4.1.7

Tags: hibernate, squirrel-sql

has anybody tried running HQL queries using SQuirrel in combination with hibernate hibernate 4.1.7.

#### Software versions:

SQuirrel 3.4.0
Oracle Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Hibernate 4.1.7-final

#### The problem's description

when I attach to Hibernate process and create a session:

1. the tab "Mapped objects" does not display any objects
2. the stack trace displays

   ```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
   java.lang.Object.getMappedClass(org.hibernate.EntityMode)
   ```
3. running a simple hql query (`select t from someTypeName t`) results in

   ```
   net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.plugins.hibernate.server.SquirrelHibernateServerException:
   Exception occured on Hibernate Server Process:
   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
   ```

Could it be that SQuirrel simply does not support Hibernate 4.1.7?

I'd appreciate any help,
Anatoly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem. Looking for a solution, I took the time and patched squirrel to work with hibernate 4.1.9.

The patch is submitted to squirrel's mailing list, awaiting approval. In the mean time, the patch is here: http://pastebin.com/yinBqy4m

Best Regards,

Petr

Comment: So how to I apply this patch to SQL Squirrel exactly?